# What's the class in tomcat jsp container that convert jsp code into servlet code?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

Jsp's are severed in the container as servlet code. I would like to know the implementation class of tomcat container that converts jsp into servlet code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Tomcat [documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jasper-howto.html):

> Tomcat 7.0 uses the Jasper 2 JSP Engine to implement the JavaServer Pages 2.1 specification.

and:

> Jasper is implemented using the servlet class org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.

Here is a [Javadoc](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/jasper/servlet/JspServlet.html) for that.

Answer (score 0):

It's in the default web.xml file for the container (which may be called something crafty like default-web.xml, but I'm not sure).

As I recall it's named "JspServlet". It's the servlet mapped by default to "*.jsp".

Answer (score 0):

To quote a line from tomcat documentation:
Jasper is implemented using the servlet class **org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet**.
More details @ http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/jasper-howto.html